# Dynamically inserting inputs with jquery in correct order

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So my main problem right now is that new inputs called new change are always inserted after the first one so instead of sth like that 1 2 3 4 5 it would be 1 5 4 3 2 1

Another thing is that after clicking add change anchor remove spells drops down below all .change divs

Here is working JS-fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/9jbngbhb/

So here is html nothing fancy:

```
    <a href="#" id="AddChampion">Add Champion</a>
    <form name="second_form" id="second_form" method="POST">
        <div id="ChampionInput">
        </div>
        <br><br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit">
    </form>
```

And here is jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    championNumber = 1;
    spellNumber=1;
    $('a#AddChampion').on('click',function(){

        $('div#ChampionInput').append(
        '<div class="Champion" data-id="'+championNumber+'">\
             <a href="#" class="Remove">Remove</a>\
             <br>\
             <input type="text" class="ChampionInput" list="champions" name="champion[]" placeholder="Champion '+championNumber+'">\
             <datalist id="champions"></datalist>\
             <a href="#" class="AddSpell">Add Spell</a>\
             <br>\
         <div>');

        championNumber++;
    });
    $('div#ChampionInput').on('click', 'a.Remove',function(){
        $(this).parent('div.Champion').remove();

    });
    $('div#ChampionInput').on('click', 'a.AddSpell',function(){
        $(
        '<div class="Spell" data-id="'+$(this).children( "div.Change").length+'">\
            <select name="change['+$(this).parent('div').data('id')+'][]">\
               <option value="Passive">Passive</option>\
               <option value="Q" selected>Q</option>\
               <option value="W">W</option>\
               <option value="E">E</option>\
               <option value="R">R</option>\
            </select>\
            <input type="text" name="championSpell['+$(this).parent('div').data('id')+'][]">\
            <br>\
            <div class="Change">\
            <textarea type="text" size="20" name="SpellDescription['+$(this).parent('div').data('id')+'][]" placeholder="Enter Description" />\
                <select name="SpellChange['+$(this).parent('.Champion').data('id')+'][0][]">\
                   <option value="buff">Buff</option>\
                   <option value="nerf">Nerf</option>\
                   <option value="new">New</option>\
                   <option value="change">Change</option>\
                   <option value="bugfix">Bugfix</option>\
                </select>\
                <a href="#" class="AddChange">Add Change </a>\
                <a href="#" class="RemoveSpell">Remove Spell</a>\
            </div>\
        </div>\
        ').appendTo('.Champion[data-id='+$(this).parent('div').data('id')+']');

    });
    $('div#ChampionInput').on('click', 'a.AddChange',function(){
        //alert($(this).parent("div.Spell").children( "div.Change").length);
        $(this).after(
           '<div class="Change">\
                <textarea type="text" size="20" name="SpellDescription['+$(this).parent('div').data('id')+'][]" placeholder="Enter Description" />\
                <select name="SpellChange['+$(this).parent().parent('div').data('id')+']['+$(this).parent("div.Spell").children( "div.Change").length+'][]">\
                   <option value="buff">Buff</option>\
                   <option value="nerf">Nerf</option>\
                   <option value="new">New</option>\
                   <option value="change">Change</option>\
                   <option value="bugfix">Bugfix</option>\
                </select>\
                <a href="#" class="RemoveChange">Remove Change</a>\
            </div>');
    });
    $('div#ChampionInput').on('click', 'a.RemoveSpell',function(){
        $(this).closest('.Spell').remove();
    });
    $('div#ChampionInput').on('click', 'a.RemoveChange',function(){
        $(this).closest('.Change').remove();
    });

});
```

Comment: You mean [http://jsfiddle.net/9jbngbhb/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/9jbngbhb/1/) ?

Comment: I don't really see any changes http://i.imgur.com/UV2E5G8.png the input still went after the first one and remove spell anchor is still at the bottom

Comment: No it (the inputs) didn't. You don't see the difference as there is no visual difference. Look at the `data-id` and you'd notice the difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
$('div#ChampionInput').on('click', 'a.AddChange',function(){
    //alert($(this).parent("div.Spell").children( "div.Change").length);
    $(this).after(
```

with

```
$('div#ChampionInput').on('click', 'a.AddChange',function(){

    var spell    = $(this).parents("div.Spell").first();
    var changes  = spell.children("div.Change");
    var changeId = changes.length;

    console.log(spell);
    console.log(changes);
    console.log(changeId);

    //console.log($(this).parent().children("div.Change").length);
    changes.last().after(
```

This should provide the `spell` parent, the `changes` children and the id for a new `change`.

Comment: is there any way to ['+$(this).parent("div.Change").children( "div.Change").length+'] increase this value by 1? i've tried addnig +1 at the end but with no effect

Comment: Hmm, that should be `[changeId+1]`, although it should already be n+1 relative to last index.